# Find max value in Java with a predefined comparator

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have a `List<Foo>`, and a compare() method taking two Foo objects and returning the 'greater' one. Is there a built-in Java method that takes the list and finds the largest one?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If `Foo` implements `Comparable<Foo>`, then [`Collections.max(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) is what you're looking for.

If not, you can create a `Comparator<Foo>` and use [`Collections.max(Collection, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) instead.

#### Example

```
// Assuming that Foo implements Comparable<Foo>
List<Foo> fooList = ...;
Foo maximum = Collections.max(fooList);
// Normally Foos are compared by the size of their baz, but now we want to
// find the Foo with the largest gimblefleck.
Foo maxGimble = Collections.max(fooList, new Comparator<Foo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo first, Foo second) {
        if (first.getGimblefleck() > second.getGimblefleck())
            return 1;
        else if (first.getGimblefleck() < second.getGimblefleck())
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the List is a subclass of Collection and so you can use the [max method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 3):

try `java.util.Collections.max`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Collections#max(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Foo` is not an inner class and `compare()` method exists in a class named `CompareClass`

You can do the following:

```
Collections.max(fooList, CompareClass::compare);
```

Which gives the `fooList` and the method `compare` as inputs to `Collections.max()` and returns the `Foo` object with the max value - according to your compare method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google Collections - they have lots of methods that help you do this sort of thing using Predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) as well. There are lots of feature to manipulate collection in a functional style.