# How to get the last element of a HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, set, hashset, treeset

I want to get last element of `HashSet`.

So there is a `last()` method in `TreeSet` so, I thought to convert set to `TreeSet` and apply `last()` method on it so that I will get last element.

I tried below code :

```java
Set<EnrollmentStatusTrack> set= new HashSet<EnrollmentStatusTrack>();
set=en.getEnrollmentStatusTracks();
TreeSet<EnrollmentStatusTrack> hashSetToTreeSet  = new TreeSet<EnrollmentStatusTrack>(set);  //here is the exception
EnrollmentStatusTrack entt=hashSetToTreeSet.last();
```

Then i get below exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.barcouncil.entity.EnrollmentStatusTrack cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
    at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)
    at com.barcouncil.dao.EnrollmentDaoImpl.searchReport(EnrollmentDaoImpl.java:994)
    at com.barcouncil.service.EnrollmentServiceImpl.searchReport(EnrollmentServiceImpl.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1909.searchReport(Unknown Source)
    at com.barcouncil.controller.EnrollmentController.searchReport(EnrollmentController.java:984)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can any one help me with this?  Or is there any other procedure to do so?

Comment: A `HashSet` *doesn't have* a defined "last" element.

Comment: If you want the „last“ element of a HashSet, just grab **any** element of it, it would be the same like @chrylis-onstrike- said. So, it sounds more like a XY-problem. What‘s the real problem of your intention?

Comment: Looking at the [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320014/1108305), it looks like the real request is to get the greatest element in the collection, according to a particular comparison function.  Voting to close this as a duplicate of an existing question that does that.

Comment: Though it looks like I should have voted to close as a duplicate of this one instead, but if I retract my close vote I can't re-vote to close.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669282/1108305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my aim is to find last element so i have done like this

```
if(en.getEnrollmentStatusTracks() != null)
            {
            Set<EnrollmentStatusTrack> set= new HashSet<EnrollmentStatusTrack>();
            set=en.getEnrollmentStatusTracks();
            List<EnrollmentStatusTrack> list  = new ArrayList<EnrollmentStatusTrack>(set); 
            Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(EnrollmentStatusTrack::getEnrollmentStatusTrackId)); 
            if(list.size() > 0)
            {
             ent=list.get(list.size() - 1);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> com.barcouncil.entity.EnrollmentStatusTrack cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

This means your `EnrollmentStatusTrack` class doesn't implement the `Comparable` interface, so you can't construct a `TreeSet<EnrollmentStatusTrack>` using a constructor that doesn't have a `Comparator<EnrollmentStatusTrack>` argument (since the `TreeSet` would have no way of comparing the elements added to it).

You can write:

```
Comprator<EnrollmentStatusTrack> comparator = ...
TreeSet<EnrollmentStatusTrack> hashSetToTreeSet  = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
hashSetToTreeSet.addAll(set);
```

where `comparator` implements the comparison logic.

Comment: thank you for reply @Eran can you please tell what is that ````comparator=.....```` what should i do there

Comment: @bharathvarma it should be an instance of a class that implement the `Comparator<EnrollmentStatusTrack>` interface (having a `int compare(EnrollmentStatusTrack o1,EnrollmentStatusTrack o2)` method). How should two `EnrollmentStatusTrack` instance be compared?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `compareTo()` method in your `EnrollmentStatusTrack` class by implementing the Comparable interface.
In the `compareTo()` method, you need to define the meaning of first/last element i.e. the ordering of the elements when the TreeSet is populated.

```
class EnrollmentStatusTrack implements Comparable<EnrollmentStatusTrack> {

    int size;

    EnrollmentStatusTrack(int s) {
        size = s;
    }

    public int compareTo(EnrollmentStatusTrack o) {
        return size - o.size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be, that with "last" you do **not** mean the last in an internal ordering of EnrollmentStatusTrack, but the *last added* (because of the terms *enrollment*, *status*, *track*).

In that case use **`LinkedHashSet`** which is ordered on addition, like `LinkedHashMap`.